# Robotic physics simulation for Reinforcement Learning

Tags: python, physics

Im new to blender and I was wondering if there is a way in which I can have the 3d model of a robot, and control its movement via an external input like a python code, and also get the positions of certain objects/points in said simulation in real time and read it in the same external code.
This is for a reinforcement learning project, and for what I have seen in some videos there is an [opensource project](https://github.com/BlenderAI/BlenderRL) for RL, but I think I first need to understand more about the physics engine and controlling it.
Any information helps, either extended video tutorials, specific documentation about these topics (I've already seen a bit of the physics engine documentation), or anything else.

Thanks :)